# HTML5 Timeline, gantt control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeline, gantt-chart

I have a requirement to create a custom HTML5 based control which a cross between a timeline and a gantt chart:

However I cannot get a hold of a 3rd party control already on the market that would cut down some dev time.
It needs to have the miniature zoomed out timeline at the top for fast navigation which when scrolled updates the main section.

Is there anything that already exists, be that open source or paid, that can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. RadiantQ [FlexyGantt](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/) does exactly what you want. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Gantt Timeline]

You can see online demos of our gantt [here](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm). When the page loads, select **FlexyGantt** on the left which is what you need and has a number of "timline" samples.

Ideal for visualizing resource utilization in a timeline, also very interactive and comes with a lot of useful features.

Comment: Hi, I need a zoomed out miniature timeline which shows a wider timescale, which can be used to quickly navigate and update the main chart.

Comment: Yes, definitely, you can show whatever you want in the timeline - fully customizable - you can show years for example. Please contact sales@radiantq.com and we will provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something I'd start from scratch - but that's just my way, I'm a Sheridan/Infragistics casualty from the early 2000s :-)

You could try to use two gantt controls as they are both just gantts. If there's nothing good for the zoomed out timeline, draw that using canvas, it's just rectangles and a draggable on top.

Comment: Its looking that way, though I can't believe there isn't already a control out there for this.